# Hive partition table by month from daily timestamp?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to create partition like `01` from date like `2017-01-02'` where `01` is month ?
I have daily sales record and I need to do query like `select * from sales where month = '01'`. So it will be better if I could partition my daily sales by month.but my data has date of format `2017-01-01` and doing 
`create table tl (columns ......) partitioned by (date <datatype> )` will create partition on daily basis which is the last thing I want .
I need to create partition dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CAUTION:-** You need to escape date column(by using ` i.e. backtick  around column name) in create statement. Because date is a datatype in hive.

You can create partitions dynamically:-
by setting below parameter in query.

`set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;`

Along with that you need to select only month part from source table:-

`insert into table sales partition(date) select columns...,SUBSTR(date,5,2) from source_table`

This insert statement will create partitions like.

> show partitions sales

`date=01
date=02
date=03
date=04`